# Wpf application deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, wpf-controls

I am new to Wpf programming. I have seen applications which have a link on the website and when you click on that the download and run in local envoirnment and these applications are built in Wpf. My question is how I can do that for my application and secondly do you need any spcial permissions from the server to deploy your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are "Click-Once" deployments. And no, you don't need especial permissions on the server.